# CSS: Crossfade animations?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm actually expecting the answer to this to be a simple and straight "NO", but I have to ask, maybe someone even already did a dirty workaround.

I made a character using **CSS3 only** and added an animation that slowly shakes his head. This can be seen as the **idle animation**. Now I added a specific **talk animation** (actually seperate, it's aplied to a different `<div>`) where he holds still and one where he shakes his head strongly. I apply the class `.shakehead` to the wrapper element via JavaScript at certain events.

```
@keyframes head-swing {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(2deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(-2deg);
    }
}

.head {
    animation: head-swing 7s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.shake .head {
    animation: head-swing 1s infinite ease-in-out;
}
```

Now, when I simply suddenly apply the class to the wrapper, the probability of changing in the middle of the animation and creating an ugly break is pretty high, so the best thing to do would be **crossfading both animations**. I want to avoid to wait for the animation end via JS, because seven seconds is a little much to wait for.

([my usecase](http://codepen.io/peternerlich/pen/gayZEQ))

If you don't know what I mean, watch [this Unity3D tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujtwmIb7sRo&feature=youtu.be&t=3m29s) for a minute.

### Is such a crossfade in any way possible? *(Probably NO)*

Comment: I have a feeling that it is possible but it would be better if I see an actual demo of your code.

Comment: can we see a live example?

Comment: The CodePen seems a bit different to your code in question. There it has two animations on the default state instead of one and both are modifying the same `transform` property (so as per spec, the latest one would win).

Comment: @Harry Yes, but effectively only one at a time is active. The first one lasts 4 seconds and the second one is 4 seconds delayed. I also wouldn't mind if I had to abandon this, if it made an animation crossfade possible.

Comment: @PeterNerlich: Oh sorry, didn't see the delay initially. I am trying out a few methods but it seems tougher than what I initially thought. I tried to just change the `animation-duration` alone instead of all and even that is causing the animation to restart.

Answer (score 0):

A crossfade is possible with the `opacity` poperty. You can use multiple poperties in the same keyframe animation (and I'm pretty surprised that a lot of people don't know that), so don't be afraid to write height changes with of you opacity changes!.

You should also put your "moving mouth" into **the same div** than you first, at **the exact same position** and do your crossfade a bit like this.

```
@keyframes crossfade1 { /*applied on the "first" mouth (still)*/
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes crossfade2 { /*applied on the "second" mouth (moving) [the height is an exemple]*/
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
       height: 3px /*the mouth is closed*/
    }
    50% {
       opacity: 1;
       height: 20px /*the mouth is open*/
    }
    100% {
       opacity: 0;
       height: 20px /*the mouth is closed*/
    }
}
```

Put the duration as the same for the two keyframe animation and voilà! You have your perfect crossfade without even using javascript!
What do you think?

Comment: Excuse me, it seems as I still haven't been clear. I have always a hard time explaning what I want... ;-)

Comment: Please see [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujtwmIb7sRo&feature=youtu.be&t=3m29s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujtwmIb7sRo&feature=youtu.be&t=3m29s) for a minute, it shows what I want